# brew install llvm but referencing /usr/bin/llvm on Mac Monterey

Tags: macos, homebrew, llvm, macos-monterey

The OS I'm using is Mac Monterey and I've installed llvm thru Homebrew and exported the path by

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin:${PATH}"
```

but it still references the version already installed in /usr/bin/llvm.
In fact, it gives me the following

```
llvm-ar failed: error executing command /usr/bin/llvm-ar @bazel-out/host/bin/external/m4_v1.4.18/libm4_lib.a-2.params
```

How can I get it to reference the one installed thru brew on /usr/local/opt/llvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me: https://tipseason.com/carbon-language-execvp-error/

MacOS ships with llvm which does not contain llvm-ar, so you will need to add it to your PATH and also export clang variables

Comment: Hmmm...now I have a new problem. Here's the response from the iMac. explorer(40884,0x116687600) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.